# Programmatically disabling screenshot in App

Tags: swift

I want to prevent taking screenshot of a page in app. 
how to do it programmatically so that screenshots cannot be taken.

Found code to detect screenshot. Can it be deleted as soon as a screenshot is taken?

```
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        // executes after screenshot
}
```

Comment: there is no way of doing that, you can check with jailbrake

Comment: If you want the user to not be able to take screenshot , because of sensitive information displayed on that certain page, you should try and do it another way because it's not such a good practice, even in @Jacob King's answer

Comment: thanks everybody for the reply

Comment: It is possible, the Amazon Prime Video app does that, if you want to make a screenshot, you will get only a black rectangle. Sorry, I don't know how to do that programmatically, but it is possible without access to the photo gallery.

Comment: there is an SO question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to prevent ScreenShots but you can prevent Screen Recording
through this code.

```swift
func detectScreenRecording(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        // executes after screenshot
        action()
    }
}
        
        
        
//Call in vewWillApper 
detectScreenRecording {
    print(UIScreen.main.isCaptured)
    if UIScreen.main.isCaptured {
        //your vier hide code
        print("self.toHide()")
    } else {
        // self.sceneDeleg(ate?.window?.isHidden = false
        //your view show code
        print("self.toShow()")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is **absolutely no way to completely prevent user from taking screenshot** during the app process, and that's because you do not have access to delete photos in the photo gallery of the user. It would totally be a security issue if you could access your user's photos.

---

**However,** there are ways to partially prevent screenshots, as described here: [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: and also no way to prevent a screenshot from another device!

Comment: @Russell exactly, you cannot prevent the user from taking picture from another device

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent user from taking screenshot, however, you can hide the content while a screenshot is taken, Use this code to do so..

```
   extension UIView {
    func hideContentOnScreenCapture() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let field = UITextField()
            field.isSecureTextEntry = true
            self.addSubview(field)
            field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
            field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

`yourView.hideContentOnScreenCapture()`

Comment: is there a SwiftUI alternative also?

Comment: @Anshul not sure mate, Sorry.

Comment: @AkashNeeli Not working in iOS 17

Answer (score 0):

Technically that is possible, via the `Photos` framework, the docs for which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos).

Example code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928647/delete-images-in-camera-roll-from-code-ios).

**However**, this will ask the user's permission first, and then again to confirm deletion; so possibly not the ideal solution. Unfortunately this is as good as it gets as Apple has the Camera Roll fairly locked down.