# How to prevent users taking screenshots of app on iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

I wanted to prevent users taking screenshots of my App and also hide it's content when it's on recent items. Do you know an equivalent to Android's `FLAG_SECURE` feature? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

Comment: You cannot prevent but you can find a workaround with deleting screenshots after they were taken. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544567/programmatically-disabling-screenshot-in-app

Comment: There's equivalent in iOS, and does it really make sense anyway? It would be quite easy to take a photo of the screen using another device.

Comment: The should read *"There's NO equivalent in iOS…"*

Comment: @AshleyMills Yes, someone can still take a photo using a separate device, but you can prevent that by not handing over your phone. What I'm after is to prevent malicious apps taking screenshots in the background without you knowing it.

Answer (score -1):

Apps (malicious or not) cannot take screenshots on iOS (in background or not), period. So **the problem does not exist in the first place.**

Apps can:

1. Render their own UI into an image, but that's not the same thing as a screenshot. It's limited to their own windows, so not a problem.
2. Record screen, but with user's authorisation every time.
3. Record videos via ReplayKit, but, again, with user's authorisation every time.

Comment: But can the user take a screenshot (or screen recording) of secured places (login, privacy-focused-chatting apps...)?