# Change the preview image of an app on Recents Screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am making a React Native app which has a secure section where the user has to enter his password to unlock the protected content. The problem is, when the user switches to another app before locking that section, a screen capture along with the unlocked content will be generated and displayed on the [Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents).

Is there a way to replace the preview with something else, a blank screen or a custom screen like the Chrome/Firefox incognito mode?

Comment: In standard Android, you would [use `FLAG_SECURE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/115145). I am not certain what the React Native equivalent is.

Comment: Agree with @CommonsWare, i guess there is no proper way. however in android there is `android:excludeFromRecents`.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Thanks for pointing out the native solutions guys. I found a [FLAG_SECURE native module](https://github.com/kristiansorens/react-native-flag-secure-android) for React Native, will test it out later. Would be great [if there's an equivalent of FLAG_SECURE on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221825/how-to-prevent-users-taking-screenshots-of-app-on-ios).

Answer (score 2):

You could listen to the app going in background and show a white/empty modal on top of the current screen

```js
import {AppState} from 'react-native'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (newAppState) => {
    if(newAppState === 'background' && newAppState !== this.state.appState) {
      // SHOW EMPTY SCREEN
    }

    if(newAppState !== 'background' && this.state.appState === 'background') {
      // HIDE EMPTY SCREEN
    }
    
    if (newAppState !== this.state.appState) {
      this.setState({ appState: newAppState })
    }
  }

  ... rest of the app ....
}
```

[AppState documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)

Comment: I like your answer. is it possible to implement it with hooks ?

Comment: Yes. In the official documentation i linked there is a hook example

Comment: well i follow the official documentation, and i've to say that works perfectly. Thank you man you won the bounty.

Comment: @Legeo I tried this way sometime I'm able to see the blank screen and sometimes I'm not able to see the app contents. Have faced the same?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-native-flag-secure-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flag-secure-android) package

```
yarn add react-native-flag-secure-android
```

**USAGE**

```
import FlagSecure from 'react-native-flag-secure-android';
 
function flagSecure(enable) {
  if (enable) {
    FlagSecure.activate();
  } else {
    FlagSecure.deactivate();
  }
}
```

**Note:** it will work for android

Comment: is this valid for ios too ?

Comment: there isn't a way to change the image in the IOS recent Image too ? i read in the comment in the original post about the library FlagSecure.

Comment: @Legeo you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screenshield which works on both android and ios

Comment: did you tried to install with yarn the library. npmjs.com/package/react-native-screenshield ? i receive an error during the installation.

Comment: @Legeo sorry I did not test this package